# How to split the page adding a page from buffer (combining :sp/vs with :b)

Tags: split

How can I open a page from buffer below or to the right of the page I'm already viewing?
By the way I want to open split the whole page not only the page I'm currently in.
imagine I have to rows and I want a column to the right of both rows that contains one file so I'll get from

```
_

to:

 |_
 |
```

And the new file is opened from buffer.
actually I would love to know the general answer for how to kinda temporarily group some splits together and add a new split below them as a whole or to the right of them as a whole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:sbuffer` is a split variant of `:buffer`. `:sb` takes the same parameters `:b` i.e. buffer numbers or buffer names.

```
:sb foo
```

You can split this below by using `:rightbelow` command or `'splitbelow'` option.

```
:rightb sb foo
```

As @Naumann said you can use `<c-w>` followed by `H`/`J`/`K`/`L` to move windows/splits however you want.

For more help see:

```
:h :sb
:h :rightb
:h 'splitbelow'
```

Answer (score 2):

two steps:

`:sp newfile`

and then press

`<c-w>J`   rsp    `<c-w>L`

Comment: I don't want to open a new file I want to open a file from buffer. A file that I've just closed.

Comment: Oh I can just use :b now on the newfile:D thanks:P